# R- How to add html formatting to a table that works with blastula?

Tags: html, r, kableextra, formattable, blastula

Blastula appears to not respect the `<style>` tags used by table formatting packages like `kableextra` and `formattable`.

Example:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(blastula)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

tbl <- dt %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()

tbl

compose_email(
  body = md(c(
    "this is my table:",
    tbl
    )))
```

Displays this when printing tbl

[image]

But this when printing `compose_email`

[image]

I think this is because blastula just prints the table, and the `kableextra` formatting is somewhere else using the `class`:

```
tbl <- dt %>%
  kbl("html")

tbl_styled <- tbl %>%
  kable_styling()

as.character(tbl)
as.character(tbl_styled)
```

This shows that the only difference when printing the styled tbl is the `<table>` tag:

```
<table class=\"table\" style=\"margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\">
```

So I suppose the only way would be to write our own table parser that puts the style inline? Unless there's already an R package that does this?

Comment: I'm curious if this was solved or not?

Comment: Unfortunately, no -- blastula appears to be unable to access the table class from kableextra. I ended up applying a little html formatting myself but mostly leaving the tables unstyled.

Comment: I went with using `gt::gt()` and `gt::as_raw_html()`.